# MathJax - Live Preview LaTeX to Unicode

Tags: latex, mathjax

How can I show into MathJax live preview the word "ñ"?

I've tried to insert This latex name Mu\~{n}oz in http://www.mathjax.org/demos/scaling-math/
But the \~{n} is not replaced to ñ

Answer (score 1):

In LaTeX one may use `\~` or the Unicode input itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

This \LaTeX{} name Mu\~{n}oz Muñoz.

\end{document}
```

MathJax is limited, but it does support using the Unicode character as input when you use:

```
\hbox{This LaTeX name Muñoz}
```

[image]

Note the switch to "text mode" via `\hbox`.